# How can I force Brasero to keep my mp3 playlist order of songs when I burn it?

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3, brasero

I have an mp3 playlist in Rhythmbox. When I drag and drop it in a Brasero data project the order of songs is lost. In fact their sorted in alhpabetical order. As you can imagine this is awful for a list of songs you want to listen to a particular order. This does not happen when I burn a list as audio and not data project.

Answer (score 4):

An audio CD consists of tracks. They are numbered and do not contain any Data about Artist etc.

A data CD however contains just that: data. Your files can be ordered by the file browser that opens it. The playlist from Rhythmbox is not part of the mp3 files. You however try to export it as an `m3u` file. Most audio player software can read that format.

Comment: Confirmed. You can save your playlist as a M3u file (but also you can use the pls format Rythmbox uses for default when saving playlists) and then open it when creating an audio project in Brasero. It will keep the order of songs as you wish. Just tried that successfully. It works even just dragging the playlist. xD

Comment: Thanks Carsten. I saved it on m3u format and insert it in brasero. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Jdpipe over on ubuntuforums.org posted a great little python script to solve this issue.
It works by creating a sequence of symlinks from a playlist (m3u) and then feeding that to Brasero.

Worked great for me!

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7503949&postcount=7

Make the python script executable and then run it from a terminal thus:

```
./m3utocd.py 'PathTo/MyPlaylist.m3u'
```